# Ubuntu cannot detect second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, intel, vga

I just got `two monitors` connected to my laptop via an `adapter`. One is a `DVI` to `HDMI`, and the other one is `VGA` to `VGA` to the adaptor.
But in the display setting, it doesn't detect the second monitor and both of them are mentioned there as one. `"Built-in display is the laptop itself."`
[image]

And it actually changes the resolution to the monitor that is connected via VGA.

I am using a Ronyse's 4-in-1 USB C-Hub, An LG and a really old DELL monitor.

Comment: Does your hardware support three monitors? Not all video systems can do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.